# Big number anomaly in SAS

Tags: sas, format, numbers

Do somebody know why the number stocked in "numero" isn't the same that the one I put in the let ?

I use SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1.

Here's my program :

```
%let ident = 4644968792486317489 ;

data _null_ ;
    numero= put(&ident.,z19.);
    call symputx('numero',numero);
run;

%put &numero. ;
```

And the log :

```
30         %let ident = 4644968792486317489 ;
31         
32         data _null_ ;
33          numero= put(&ident.,z19.);
34          call symputx('numero',numero);
35         run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
      

36         
37         %put &numero. ;
4644968792486317056
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SAS stores numbers as 8 byte floating point values. Therefore there is a limit to the maximum integer that can be stored exactly (or really exactly without gaps).  They even publish a [table with the maximum value](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

[image]

And a function you can use to determine the maximum value.

```
3    %put %sysfunc(constant(exactint),comma23.);
9,007,199,254,740,992
```

Looks like your "number" is really an identifier. So store it as character to begin with and you will not have these problems.

```
data want;
  length numero $19;
  numero = "&ident";
  numero = translate(right(numero),'0',' ');
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. The problem is that I want to modify this number to anonymize it with a function I create that modify the diferent parts of the number (I'm using substr(numero,x,2) and a mathematical calcul in order to do that). So I must keep it as a number.

Comment: Your comment is confusing.  You cannot use substr() with a number. You can convert the sub strings into numbers and operate on them as long as the numbers generated from the substrings are small enough that they can be represented using SAS's floating point numbers it should work.  Sounds like you should ask a new question that explains your actual problem.

Comment: I think I can, for a 16 length number my code works :
%let ident = 4644968792486317489 ;

data _null_ ;
 numero= put(&ident.,z19.);
 v11=substr(numero,1,3);
 v12=f(v11);
 v13=f2(v12);
 ...
 v1x=fx-1(v1x-1);
 reslt1 = v1x;

 v21=substr(numero,4,2);
 v22=f(v21);
 v23=f2(v22);
 ...
 v2x=fx-1(v2x-1);
 reslt2 = reslt1*100 + v2x;

 ...

 v81=substr(numero,18,2);
 v82=f(v81);
 v83=f2(v82);
 ...
 v8x=fx-1(v8x-1);
 reslt8 = reslt7*100 + v8x;

 ID_ANO = reslt8 ;

run;

Comment: And your log will have type conversion notes all over it. Use SUBSTRN to get substrings on a number. Your code does not work without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SAS `MD5` function to anonymize strings.  Don't forget MACRO is really just text processing.

```
%let ident = 4644968792486317489 ;
%let numero = %sysfunc(MD5(&ident));
```

or in DATA Step

```
data ... ;
  numero = MD5("&ident");
```

In certain situations you might associate a monotonic serial value to an identity value.

```
%let ident = 4644968792486317489 ;

%if not %symexist(i&ident) %then %do;
  %let i&ident = %sysfunc(monotonic());
  %put new serial;
%end;

%put i&ident=&&i&ident;
----- LOG -----
i4644968792486317489=1
```